# Rake FileList exclude method works in irb but not my rakefile

Tags: rake

Goal : Collect all files, complete with directory structure, matching a directory structure.

Wrinkle: Need to filter out a pesky undesired directory that matches but is thankfully uniquely named 'do-not-want'. Actual string changed to protect the innocent.

- source/dir1/content/scripts - **ok**
- source/dir2/subdir1/content/scripts - **ok**
- source/dir3/do-not-want/content/scripts - **well... do not want**

The script below works but I have to do a separate check for the undesired path which should not be necessary. When I test this same FileList in irb with the exclude it works as desired. From my rakefile I see the **do-not-want** directories being returned by the FileList.

```
FileList['source/**/content/scripts'].exclude('do-not-want').each do |f|
    unless /do-not-want/ =~ f #hmm why does the exclude above not actually exclude do-not-want directories?
        Dir.chdir(f) do |d|
            puts "directory changed to #{d} and copying scripts from #{d} to common directory #{target}"
            FileUtils.cp_r('.', target)
        end         
    end
end
```

Surely I am doing something dumb.

*Bonus points*: if you help me learn rake/ruby and show me a better way to accomplish same goal while defeating the wrinkle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `FileList['source/**/content/scripts'].exclude(/\/do-no-want\//)` to filter out paths which contain "/do-no-want/" substring.

Try adding output to your rake file, so you can see and debug what's going on there.